# ValidationRule globally apply ValidatesOnTargetUpdated to true

Tags: wpf, validation

Is there a way in a style to set ValidatesOnTargetUpdated to true for all ValidationRules?  I currently have the potential of including 2 rules for each textbox.  And that means I have to add ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False" for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because ValidationRules are a property of a binding, styles are applied to FrameworkElements.  Two completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom rule derived from ValidationRule, you could set the value in the constructor. This means you do not have to set the value for each usage.